# Can I send cash tips in React Native using Stripe

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I have a React Native app that has 2 types of end users.  I would like User-A to be able to send cash tips to User-B.  I also want the business to be able to retain a % of each tip as a convenience fee.
What is the best way to implement this?

I have Stripe in mind but I don't want to inconvenience User-A by having him make 2 transactions.  I would prefer the tip go to the business account first, then from there, my preference is to have the code automatically and programmatically send the relevant funds to User-B.  If not, then have User-B manually withdraw his tips.  But I have no idea how to go about this.  Is Stripe is even the best solution?

Any ideas are much appreciated.

PS: This must be a common use case.  Why is it so hard?

Answer (score 0):

This is a use-case for [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect). In order for User B to receive funds, they'll need a Stripe Connect Account. For someone to receive payment, their identity will need to be verified, so that is why they'll need a Connect account. The flow you are describing is a [Destination Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges), which works with [Express](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts) and [Custom](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts) Connect account types. This shouldn't affect your React Native code much. The main difference, as you can see from the Destination Charge link I provided, is that you'll need to specify `transfer_data[destination]` when you create the Payment Intent on your server.

Comment: Would the following example work with the system you described?

User-A sends a tip to User-B for $10.  The business gets $1 and User-B receives $9 all automatically without any further input from User-A or the business.

Comment: Yeah. Take a look at the docs I shared above.